# Uploading zipped SQLite database to server

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, alamofire

I'm writing an app that collects various data, saves it in a database. I want to zip the database and upload it to a server using Alamofire, but I can't get it to work. I'm not getting any errors, but the zip file doesn't appear on the server.

The server uses self-signed certificates, which I tried to override. Maybe the problem is there?

Here is my code:

```
func uploadZippedDB(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void){
    let url = Constants.zipUploadURL

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=*****"
    ]

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { 
        if let zipPath = self.zipDatabase(){
            let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
                url: .disableEvaluation
            ]

            self.manager = SessionManager(session: Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session, delegate: Alamofire.SessionManager.default.delegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))

            let zipURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: zipPath)

            self.manager!.upload(zipURL, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers)
                .uploadProgress(closure: { progress in // main queue by default
                    print("Zip Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")

                })
                .response(){
                    response in

                    let _ = self.manager

                    if response.error != nil {
                        print("An unknown error occurred while trying to upload zip, error: \(String(describing: response.error))")
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }

                    if let resp = response.response {
                        if resp.statusCode >= 300 {
                            NSLog("HTTP error while uploading zip, status code: %@", resp.statusCode)
                            completion(false)
                            return
                        }
                        print(resp)
                    }
                    completion(true)               
            }                
        } else {
            NSLog("couldn't upload zipped database")
            completion(false)
            return            
       }
    }    
}
```

I'm getting this response from the server:

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
  Connection = "Keep-Alive";
  "Content-Length" = 0;
  "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
  Date = "Fri, 07 Jul 2017 10:40:43 GMT";
  "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
  Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
  "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17";
} }
```

Content-Length is 0, so it seems like it's not actually uploading any data. But the zip file definitely exists at zipPath.

How can I get it to upload correctly? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: First test your service with Postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I just did this. I'm getting the exact same response, with status code 200 and the same headers as above.